# webScriptNameForSelector and javascript method with underscore

Tags: javascript, macos, webview

I am using a WebView in my application and it the page I am loading has some existing javascript function calls that were used in a windows environment and should now be used in a mac application.  My issue is that the current javascript (ported from a windows app where the following works) function calls objective C like this:

```
function callObjectiveC
{
   window.external.MY_ObjectiveCFunction();
}
```

I have been trying to use:

```
+ (NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    if (sel == @selector(MyObjectiveCFunction)) 
    {
    return @"My_ObjectiveCFunction";
    }   
}
```

based on: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebScripting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html but to no avail.  Is there a way to do this? I can call the objective C method whatever I want I just need to be able to map that to what is in the existing javascript.

Thanks,
c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out a solution:

```
- (id)invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript:(NSString *)name withArguments:(NSArray *)args
{
NSLog(@"invoke undefined method: %@", name);
if([name isEqualToString:@"My_ObjectiveCFunction"])
{
    return NSSelectorFromString(@"My_ObjectiveCFuntion");   
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Recently I came to the same question and solved it with similar solution. But according to the document, the return value of `invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript:withArguments:` is defined as `Return Value
The result of invoking the undefined method.` So should I call the corresponding method directly or return a selector as you said?

Answer (score 0):

you just shouldn't use underscore characters. That is basically the only valid solution unfortunately.

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html%20here) at the apple docs

I don't think using invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript: is a good idea here

Answer (score -1):

Missing colon.

if (sel == @selector(MyObjectiveCFunction:))

Comment: This didn't work.  I think it has something to do with the _ in the method names.