# Getting invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript to work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, wkwebview

I am trying to get Javascript-Swift interface work with WKWebView and someone seems to have got it working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813929/webscriptnameforselector-and-javascript-method-with-underscore).

However I am unable to get it working in Swift (I am new to Swift and newer to Obj-C). I tried following code in ViewController.swift with WKWebView added to Main.storyboard and connected:

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var wkWebView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8080")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        wkWebView!.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wkWebView!.load(request)
    }
}

extension WKWebView {
    open override func invokeUndefinedMethod(fromWebScript name: String!, withArguments arguments: [Any]!) -> Any! {
        return "Hello From Swift"
    }
}
```

and on HTML side:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <input type=text id='i'/>
    <input type=button value='Submit' onclick='document.getElementById(\"i\").value = window.external.MY_ObjectiveCFunction();'>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on Submit button nothing happens.  If I use `document.getElementById("i") = "hello"`, it works though. @ctrlspace seems to have got it working somehow (See link above).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found an old article which was written for an ancient `WebView` of macOS, not for `WKWebView`.

You use `WKScriptMessageHandler` to make interaction between JavaScript and Swift, when using `WKWebView`.

ViewController.swift:

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var wkWebView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")! //Simplified for testing
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        wkWebView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wkWebView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "mySwiftMessage") //<-
        wkWebView.load(request)
    }

    //...
}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        switch message.name {
        case "mySwiftMessage":
            if let callbackName = message.body as? String {
                message.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("\(callbackName)('Hello From Swift');", completionHandler: nil)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function myCallback(value) {
                document.getElementById("i").value = value;
            }
        </script>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <input type=text id='i'/>
        <input type=button value='Submit' onclick='window.webkit.messageHandlers.mySwiftMessage.postMessage("myCallback");'>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### ADDITION

To make `WKWebView` work on prior iOS's than 11, you just need to instantiate it programmatically:

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var wkWebView: WKWebView! //<- NOT an IBOutlet

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfig.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webConfig.userContentController.add(self, name: "mySwiftMessage")
        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: webConfig)
        view.addSubview(wkWebView)
        //You may need to add some constraints...
        //And create a better `index.html` for iOS...
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        wkWebView.load(request)
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the completely working solution..  I would also like to make it work for UIWebView to support iOS 9.0+ since WKWebView is only for iOS11+.  Is it possible?

Comment: I could not find such an elegant solution for UIWebView.  Seems only workarounds are available (such as loading a custom url)

Comment: You are mistaking the availability of [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview), which is available since iOS 8. Just that you cannot use storyboard for `WKWebView` before iOS 11. You just need to instantiate your `WKWebView` programmatically.

Comment: Excellent.. That worked too.. I wish I can upvote you more than once.. Thanks a ton!!